# Construction of a cover from a locally finite closed cover

Tags: general-topology

Let $\{ F_i \mid i\in \Delta \}$ be a locally finite closed covering of a Hausdorff space $X$. Is $\{ \operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(F_i)) \mid i\in \Delta \}$ a **cover** of $X$?
Where $\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int}(F_i))$= Closure of interior of $F_i$.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Indeed, assume the converse. Let $x\in X$ be an arbitrary point not covered by the modified family. Since the family $\mathcal F=\{F_i\}$ is locally finite there exists a neighborhood $U_x$ of the point $x$ which intersects only a finite subfamily $\mathcal F_x$ of the family $\mathcal F$. Put $V_x=U_x\setminus\bigcup_{F\in\mathcal F_x}\operatorname{Cl}(\operatorname{Int} F)$. By our assumption, $V_x$ is a neighborhood of the point $x$. But $V_x\subset \bigcup_{F\in \mathcal F_x} F\setminus\operatorname{Int} F)$, so it is nowhere dense, a contradiction.